# Python pool.starmap with list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there a function similar to pools.starmap that can be used with list of dictionaries?

Instead of :
`pools.starmap(func, iterable_of_tuple)`

You would have:
`pools.starmapdict(func, iterable_of_dictionaries)`

so that the function starmapdict would be responsible for unpacking the dictionary of argument of the function.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this. 

A solution is to use map and then unpack the arguments yourself inside the ´func´ function

Comment: What happens when you use the standard starmap initiated with an iterable of dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I used is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
    
data = [{"name": "Delphi", "age": 13}, {"name": "Orion", "age":24}, {"name": "Asher"}, {"name": "Baccus"}]
    
def fun_wrapper(dict_args):
    return fun(**dict_args)
    
def fun(name="Iseult", age=30):
    print(name, age)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as pool:
        pool.map(fun_wrapper, data)
```

The fun_wrapper function is responsible for unpacking the dictionary and giving it to the fun function.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda an old question but I have the answer:
**DON'T USE STARMAP; USE MAP**.

Given,

```
pool.starmap(func, list_of_dictionaries)
```

Instead do:

```
pool.map(func, list_of_dictionaries)
```

### Context

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap),

> The difference between map() and starmap() parallels the distinction between function(a,b) and function(*c).

So using starmap with a list of dictionaries will unpack the dictionaries keys as the arguments; which is not what you want at all.

## Full example

#### Broken using starmap

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
data = [
 {"name": "Delphi"}, {"name": "Orion"}, {"name": "Asher"}, {"name": "Baccus"}
]
def fun(*args):
 print(args)

with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.starmap(fun,data)
#Prints: """
$> name
$> name
$> name
$> name
"""
```

#### Working using map

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
data = [
 {"name": "Delphi"}, {"name": "Orion"}, {"name": "Asher"}, {"name": "Baccus"}
]
def fun(object):
 print(object)

with Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.map(fun,data)
#Prints: """
$> {"name": "Delphi"}
$> {"name": "Orion"}
$> {"name": "Asher"}
$> {"name": "Baccus"}
"""
```

Comment: It actually does not work the way I would like it to. In your code, "object" is still a dictionnary. The fun function I would like to use is more like : def fun(name="Iseult", age=30): print(name, age) I just made an answer with the only solution I found to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following:

```
pools.starmap(func, zip(iterable_of_dictionaries.keys(), iterable_of_dictionaries.values())
```

Edit 1:

```
>>> d = {"a": "1", "b": "2"}

>>> print(d.items())
dict_items([('a', '1'), ('b', '2')])


>>> print(d.keys(), d.values())
dict_keys(['a', 'b']) dict_values(['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Isn't `zip(d.keys(), d.values())` the same as `d.items()`?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: The question does not ask about a dictionary, but about a list of dictionaries.